# JSON file awkwardness, and endpoint GET and POST request with it

Tags: jquery, json, endpoint

So I'm fairly new to webapps and I need to make GET and POST requests to this endpoint that me and my group are working on together.
http://54.87.197.206:8080/SparkServer/admin/api/v1/listOf/accounts

I was easily able to make a GET request for another endpoint, 
http://54.87.197.206:8080/SparkServer/admin/api/v1/listOf/users

but when I tried to do the same for accounts nothing would print so upon further inspection I just copied the accounts endpoint into a JSON file, and looked at the JSON format that was provided by the endpoint. Then looking at the file this is what the JSON file looks like this:

```
[
    {
     "owner":null,
     "accountNum":1172162121,
     "balance":10000000000000,
     "creationDate":null,
     "type":CHECKING
    },

{
    "owner":Name: Tom Eater userID: 1172354496 Password: AntsAreTasty Admin: false antEatingAntEater1@gmail.com 5712342393 AntEater,
    "accountNum":1171392624,
    "balance":499750000,
    "creationDate":null,
    "type":CHECKING
},
{
    "owner":Name: andy roid userID: 1716768276 Password: studio Admin: false android@gmail.com 455148 android,
    "accountNum":1689835853,
    "balance":150,
    "creationDate":null,
    "type":SAVINGS
},

{
    "owner":Name: henry lopez userID: 1615704459 Password: henrylopez Admin: false h@x.com 6895 henrylopez,
    "accountNum":1360787709,
    "balance":150,
    "creationDate":null,
    "type":SAVINGS
},


{
    "owner":Name: water water userID: 1357055152 Password: waterwater Admin: false g@x.com 6895 waterwater,
    "accountNum":1388328287,
    "balance":150,
    "creationDate":null,
    "type":CHECKING
},

{
    "owner":Name: bob lopez userID: 1287793332 Password: boblopez Admin: false h@x.com 9865 boblopez,
    "accountNum":1103883358,
    "balance":1498000000000,
    "creationDate":null,
    "type":CHECKING
},

{
    "owner":Name: Second Rate userID: 1575771782 Password: twice Admin: false numberTwo@secondrate.com 16834943534 second,
    "accountNum":1745061298,
    "balance":150,
    "creationDate":null,
    "type":SAVINGS
},

{
    "owner":Name: third heard userID: 1743678273 Password: trice Admin: false we@d.com 4 third,
    "accountNum":1759645352,
    "balance":150,
    "creationDate":null,
    "type":SAVINGS
},

{
    "owner":Name: fourth quad userID: 1368217803 Password: north Admin: false south@east.west 444444 fourth,
    "accountNum":1535968324,
    "balance":300000000000,
    "creationDate":null,
    "type":SAVINGS
},

{
    "owner":Name: fife fife userID: 1415822540 Password: five5 Admin: false five@s.co 555 fifth,
    "accountNum":1389082491,
    "balance":100000000,
    "creationDate":null,
    "type":SAVINGS
}
]
```

my question is if the file is wrong? If not then how would I do a GET and POST request to this endpoint using jQuery. Would I have to do some kind of nested get jquery? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code I used to

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>

$(function () {
  $.getJSON('http://54.87.197.206:8080/SparkServer/admin/api/v1/listOf/users',function (response) {
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.id),
        $('<td>').text(item.name),
        $('<td>').text(item.email),
        $('<td>').text(item.username),
        $('<td>').text(item.password),
        $('<td>').text(item.phoneNumber)).appendTo('#records_table');
        // $('#records_table').append($tr);
    });
  });
});




</script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
 
      <h3>List of Users</h3>
      <table id="records_table" border = "2">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Password</th>
          <th>Phone Number</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tablebody"></tbody>
      </table>
      
      
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and then the code I used to get into the Account:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>

$(function () {
  $.getJSON('accounts.json',function (response) {
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.owner),
        $('<td>').text(item.accountNum),
        $('<td>').text(item.balance),
        $('<td>').text(item.creationDate),
        $('<td>').text(item.type)).appendTo('#records_table');
        // $('#records_table').append($tr);
    });
  });
});




</script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
 
      <h3>List of Users</h3>
      <table id="records_table" border = "2">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>Owner</th>
          <th>Account Number</th>
          <th>Balance</th>
          <th>Creation Date</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tablebody"></tbody>
      </table>
      
      
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share the code what you tried to access the account page data.Then only we can assist you

Comment: The JSON that you provided in the question is in fact wrong. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, basically is the endpoint that was provided to me wrong? If it isn't how do I properly cycle through it?

Comment: JSON string should be in double quotes.see [docs](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: I had a feeling, i just needed to confirm because it kinda looked like it was trying to be a nested json , it should be something like this correct? 
"owner":"Name: Tom Eater userID: 1172354496 Password: AntsAreTasty Admin: false antEatingAntEater1@gmail.com 5712342393 AntEater",